# Combine columns from 2 queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 queries where I group by week, by quarter and year using added_on, the problem comes in when I try to combine the queries since the first query weeks are from 1,2,3,4,5,....,25, it has transactions in every week of the year and the second query is 1,4,5,8,15,25 because it does not have transactions on some weeks and I need for both to have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,...,25 is there any way to achieve this?

transaction table

| id | value | added_on | currency_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2020/01/20 |  |
| 2 | 320 | 2020/2/10 |  |

currency table

| id | type |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | USD |
| 2 | EUR |

My query is looking like this

```
SELECT   
  week_usd,
  week_eur,
  total_usd,
  total_eur,
  quarter_year
FROM   
  (SELECT   
    WEEK(transaction.added_on) AS week_usd,   
    SUM(transaction.value) AS total_usd,   
    CONCAT(QUARTER(transaction.added_on)," ", YEAR(transaction.added_on)) AS quarter_year   
   FROM transaction   
   JOIN currency ON transaction.currency_id = currency.id   
   WHERE   
     currency.type = 'USD'
   GROUP BY 1,3
   ) AS table1,   
   (SELECT   
    WEEK(transaction.added_on) AS week_eur,   
    SUM(transaction.value) AS total_eur,   
    CONCAT(QUARTER(transaction.added_on)," ", YEAR(transaction.added_on)) AS quarter_year   
   FROM transaction   
   JOIN currency ON transaction.currency_id = currency.id   
   WHERE   
     currency.type = 'EUR'
   GROUP BY 1,3
   ) AS table2
```

The problem with my query is that it will display like this

| week_usd | week_eur | total_usd | total_eur | quarter_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 100 | 150 | 1 2020 |
| 1 | 1 | 100 | 150 | 1 2020 |
| 2 | 1 | 100 | 150 | 1 2020 |
| 3 | 1 | 100 | 150 | 1 2020 |
| 4 | 1 | 100 | 150 | 1 2020 |
| 5 | 1 | 100 | 150 | 1 2020 |
| 6 | 1 | 100 | 150 | 1 2020 |
| 7 | 1 | 100 | 150 | 1 2020 |
| 8 | 1 | 100 | 150 | 1 2020 |

Comment: Can you provide more input samples and an output for the specific provided input data?

Answer (score 0):

You need first to create unique list of dates before getting joins of totals:

```
Select date_list.quarter_year
    , date_list.week
    , USD.total_usd
    , EUR.total_eur
from 
    ( select distinct CONCAT(QUARTER(transaction.added_on)," ", YEAR(transaction.added_on)) AS quarter_year
        , WEEK(transaction.added_on) week 
        from transaction 
    ) as date_list 
    Left Join (
        select CONCAT(QUARTER(transaction.added_on)," ", YEAR(transaction.added_on)) AS quarter_year
            , WEEK(transaction.added_on) week 
            , SUM(transaction.value) AS total_usd
        from transaction 
            join currency on transaction.currency_id = currency.id 
        where currency.type = 'USD'
        group by 1,2 
    ) as USD on date_list.quarter_year = USD.quarter_year and date_list.week = USD.week 
    Left Join (
        select CONCAT(QUARTER(transaction.added_on)," ", YEAR(transaction.added_on)) AS quarter_year
            , WEEK(transaction.added_on) week 
            , SUM(transaction.value) AS total_eur
        from transaction 
            join currency on transaction.currency_id = currency.id 
        where currency.type = 'EUR'
        group by 1,2 
    ) as EUR on date_list.quarter_year = EUR.quarter_year and date_list.week = EUR.week ;
```